# "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream" for normal users

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

A third party vendor is adding authentication (yay!), but it doesn't always work for us (boo!).

***When the C# application is run "as administrator" it works fine***. However, when the application is run as a normal (non-administrator) user it fails with the message

"Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"

We are explicitly setting to TLS 1.2

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

We are

- executing a 4.6 .NET C# WCF client
- that consumes an HTTPS web service
- using TLS1.2
- on a Windows Server 2012 platform

Comment: Have you talked to the third party vendor?  It's their code, so they're best positioned to answer any issues with it.

Comment: They don't know. They point back to something with our environment since it works when running as the ADMIN user but not as any other users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We figured it out with the help of [Getting "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority" even though ServerCertificateValidationCallback returns true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988005/getting-could-not-establish-secure-channel-for-ssl-tls-with-authority-even-tho) as well as [winhttpcertcfg giving access to IIS user in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678584/winhttpcertcfg-giving-access-to-iis-user-in-windows-7) too.

The problem was that the certificate was installed for *Trusted People* for the "computer" account. When running in Admin mode, or as a user that has admin privileges, it worked fine. However, when run as our "*service account*" (in quotes because it's not a true service account) -- the service account didn't have permission to read the certificate.

We found that digging into the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\crypto\rsa\machinekeys` directory and changing the read permission for the appropriate cert worked.

We didn't like the proposed solution of using `icacls` to change the read permission of the installed certificate (partially because of the daunting task of actually finding the correct cert entry.)

We figure out that we could run `mmc.exe` as the *service account* and then install it to the *Trusted People* level for that account. And ***then*** our non-admin application could read the cert and establish the connection.

Comment: Glad you found the problem.   And thank you for sharing the answer - it will help folks down the road :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be different than OPs original problem but my issue was that I had my IIS Application using Windows Auth **Impersonation** so it was trying to access the cert file in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\crypto\rsa\machinekeys` with the impersonated user who did not have the rights to do so.

I changed the design to turn Impersonation off and this issue ceased to exist.